# Git commit on merge and deleted branch

Tags: git, github

I have a very weird situation.

I have created my branch from `develop` branch. I wanted to delete 1 file named `SendEmail.xml` and after approval it got merged into the develop branch.

It didn't do anything after that like deleting my branch from locally or anything.

After a day I remember there are few references in other files(named `A.xml` and `B.xml` as well. So I just deleted the reference of `SendEmail.xml` from both the files and commit my changes to remote branch and created a **Pull Request** again.

Now when I created the **Pull Request** again, it is showing all the files. 2 as modified changes and `SendEmail.xml` as deleted even though the file is not available in `develop` branch.

**What I tried**

I tried several ways to resolve this.

1. I tried rebasing my branch to `develop` and push the changes again. But it still showing all 3 files.
2. I tried pulling data again but same result.

Comment: Q: What is your Git provider?  GitHub?  Or GitLab, BitBucket, Azure DevOps or some other provider?  Q: What Git client are you using?  The Git CLI ("git status", "git add", "git commt -m", etc)?  Your Git provider's web interface?  Tortoise Git?  Something else entirely?

Comment: Try to reset your local changes to the `develop` branch. If it's not there on develop branch then it only means that you have some untracked changes in your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create a new branch from `origin/develop`, and make sure `SendEmail.xml` is not there.

Then, in that new local branch, you can:

- delete the other files
- commit and push the new branch
- make a new PR from said new branch